# Why ambiguous reference error while using Left without parameters type?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I found "ambiguous reference to overloaded definition" while trying to practice scala interview question.

I was trying to find the outcome of following code block which results in compilation error :

Code :

```
for {
  v1 <- Left[Int,Int](1)
  v2 <- Right(2)
  v3 <- Right(3)
  v4 <- Left(4)
} yield v1 + v2 + v3 + v4
```

Error :

```
<pastie>:17: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method + in class Int of type (x: Char)Int
and  method + in class Int of type (x: Byte)Int
match argument types (Nothing)
} yield v1 + v2 + v3 + v4
                     ^
```

Why Scala compiler gives **ambiguous reference error** when we specified type only on **v1** field but not on **v4** ?

I also tried following version with different parameter type in v1 and v4 and it worked !

```
for {
  v1 <- Left[String,Int]("1")
  v2 <- Right(2)
  v3 <- Right(3)
  v4 <- Left[Int, Int](4)
} yield v1 + v2 + v3 + v4
```

And the output is :

```
res20: scala.util.Either[Any,Int] = Left(1)
```

I tried with one more version which also resulted into error :

```
for {
  v1 <- Left(1)
  v2 <- Right(2)
  v3 <- Right(3)
  v4 <- Left(4)
} yield v1 + v2 + v3 + v4
```

output :

```
<console>:17: error: value + is not a member of Nothing
       } yield v1 + v2 + v3 + v4
```

How exactly the for comprehension works here with `Left` and `Right` ? Why the first and last case are not working in my example ?

Comment: You are writing a `for` over **eithers**, thus the compiler needs to keep track of both the _left_ and _right_ types. Your examples do not provide those types nor give enough info for the compiler to properly infer them. For example `v4 <- Left(4)` what should be the type of `v4`? For you it is obvious it should be **Int** but for the compiler it simple doesn't know, so it assumes **Nothing** but you can not sum an **Int** with a **Nothing**. In general, this is not problem since usually you won't have hard-coded values _(since you can manually reduce the expression)_ but calls to methods.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, Nice explanation to understand the problem. But why scala compile does not generate any error for the first case in my example where I have specified type only for v1 field ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?, that first version does generate an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because there's no common inferred types and you didn't specify the types for all the `Either`.

So

```
scala> for (v1 <- Right(2)) yield v1
res13: scala.util.Either[Nothing,Int] = Right(2)
```

Solution is to give them common types

```scala
for {
  v1 <- Left[Int,Int](1)
  v2 <- Right[Int,Int](2)
  v3 <- Right[Int,Int](3)
  v4 <- Left[Int,Int](4)
} yield v1 + v2 + v3 + v4
```

Which gives `Left(1)`.  This result makes sense due to `Either` being right-biased and for comprehension serving as a `flatMap`.

According to the documentation:
*"Either is right-biased, which means that Right is assumed to be the default case to operate on. If it is Left, operations like map, flatMap, ... return the Left value unchanged"*
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html

Comment: Why scala compiler does not generate any error for second example in my question when I tried with `String` type for field `v1 <- Left[String,Int]("1")`

Comment: Because it's now able to infer the type as `Either[Any,Int]`, making it a common type. It's still suspicious in terms of results though, because when you change the yield to `yield v1` or `yield v2`, they all return `Left(1)`.  I'm thinking it's an issue around `Either` itself

Comment: _"though that doesn't make sense as a logical answer"_ WDYM?

Comment: With all those operations there, I can't see why we would expect `Left(1)`.  It's not an order thing either, as this also gives Left(1). 
```scala
for {
  v2 <- Right[Int,Int](2)
  v1 <- Left[Int,Int](1)
} yield v2 + v1
```

Comment: `Left[Int,Int](1)` can also be written as `Left(1).withRight[Int]`

Comment: @kanielc **Either** is right-biased, its `flatMap` operation _(which is what `for` is doing under the hood)_ proceeds only if the current value is a **Right**, once the result is a **Left** all further operations are short-circuited. That is the whole point of using **Either**, so not sure what you say that it doesn't make sense. Even more, how would you even do `v1 + v2` if there wasn't any `v2` in the first place. - What is true is that a `for` expression of hardcoded **Either** values doesn't make much sense, since you can always reduce the result in your mind and replace it with a constant

Comment: Okay I went to read the documentation and this explains it well

"Either is right-biased, which means that Right is assumed to be the default case to operate on. If it is Left, operations like map, flatMap, ... return the Left value unchanged"

Comment: @kanielc  @ Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez : Thanks for the highly informative discussion.  Could you please update answer with the conclusion in last comment. So I can accept the answer.